# when i am installing perl in ubuntu systems the systems replying as permission denied

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, installation, ubuntu-12.04

I just want to install the asterisk software. To do that I need to install perl cmd and more. However when I try to install perl in ubuntu, the system replies: permission denied.

Here is the command I used:

```
php05@linux05:~$ cd /usr/local
php05@linux05:/usr/local$ 
php05@linux05:/usr/local$ wget http://asterisk.gnuinter.net/files/asterisk-perl-0.08.tar.gz
--2013-04-25 16:56:59--  http://asterisk.gnuinter.net/files/asterisk-perl-0.08.tar.gz Resolving
asterisk.gnuinter.net (asterisk.gnuinter.net)... 69.54.200.117
Connecting to asterisk.gnuinter.net
(asterisk.gnuinter.net)|69.54.200.117|:80... connected. HTTP request
sent, awaiting response... 200 OK Length: 13217 (13K)
[application/x-tar] asterisk-perl-0.08.tar.gz: Permission denied

Cannot write to `asterisk-perl-0.08.tar.gz' (Permission denied).
php05@linux05:/usr/local$
```

How can I get the proper permissions to do this?

Comment: It seems like you don't have the permissions to write /usr/local. Try sudo wget ...

Comment: @BlackBear :give complete permission command.

Comment: in normal case how we can give the permissions to files.?

Comment: It's chmod, in this case you want chmod u+w http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod

Comment: Any reason why not to use the Ubuntu package? http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libasterisk-agi-perl -- install with `sudo apt-get install libasterisk-agi-perl`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the command using  "**sudo** wget http://asterisk.gnuinter.net/files/asterisk-perl-0.08.tar.gz", since you are trying to download the file in to /usr/local folder, and type your password once again and here goes.